# How to convert this methods to the new Vue 3 Composition API?

Tags: vue.js, vuejs3

I'm updating some Vue 3 components to use the new Composition API.

The code needs to be able to run inside the new .

I'm still learning, and I couldn't find an example of how to do it on the internet.

Thanks in advance!

```js
export default {
  data() {
    return {
      productName: '',
      productFeatures: '',
      temperature: 0.1,
      generatedText: '',
      loading: false,
      aviso: false
    }
  },
  methods: {
    generateText() {
      this.loading = true;
      let prompt = `This is a test ${this.productName}.`;
      axios.post('https://example.com', {
        model: "XXXXXX",
        logprobs: 1,
        max_tokens: 500,
        prompt: prompt,
        temperature: 0.3
        // temperature: 0.7,
      }, {
        headers: {
          'Authorization': 'Bearer XXXXXXXXXXXXX'
        }
      }).then(response => {
        this.generatedText = response.data.choices[0].text;
        this.loading = false;
        this.aviso = true;
      });
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is an example how you can translate it to composition API way. You still need to learn how Vue 3 work.

```html
<script setup>
const {
    productName,
    productFeatures,
    temperature,
    generatedText,
    loading,
    aviso
} = reactive({ productName: '', productFeatures: '', temperature: 0.1, generatedText: '', loading: false, aviso: false })

function generateText() {
    loading = true;
    let prompt = `This is a test ${productName}.`;
    axios.post('https://example.com', {
        model: "XXXXXX",
        logprobs: 1,
        max_tokens: 500,
        prompt: prompt,
        temperature: 0.3
    }, {
        headers: {
            'Authorization': 'Bearer XXXXXXXXXXXXX'
        }
    }).then(response => {
        generatedText = response.data.choices[0].text;
        aviso = true;
    }).finally(() => loading = false);
}
</script>
```

I changed the place where loading value is changing to false in a function because if you have an error it will load end less.

Instead of `reactive()` you can use `ref()` like this:

```html
<script setup>
const productName = ref('')
const productFeatures = ref('')
const temperature = ref(0.1)
const generatedText = ref('')
const loading = ref(false)
const aviso = ref(false)

function generateText() {
    // Using ref instead of reactive means you need to get
    // values by .value and same way assign them.
    loading.value = true
    ...
}
</script>
```

`Ref<T>` are for simple variables, not objects. They will work correct when you assign something direct to `.value = "bla"` but no, if it is an object, and you want to update value inside of that object `.value.title = "bla"`. `Ref<T>` won't know that you updated `.title` value, so you lose reactivity your template won't update title.

You won't lose reactivity if you use `Ref<T>` like this:

```js
const data = ref({ title: "Some title" })

data.value = { ...data.value, title: "Some new title" }
```

Read about what `...` spread operator do if you don't know.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the help! Now I'm understanding better how to use reactive objects :D